# Why do I get such a low accuracy despite having good metrics?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, convolutional-neural-network, image-segmentation

I'm working on an image segmentation problem. I'm fine-tuning the network, and when displaying the metrics I obtain, I have some doubts.
I am going to provide some details about the network:

1. Solver: SGD
2. Loss: Dice coefficient

Below, I attach the results:

1. loss: -0.7114
2. accuracy: 2.3608e-06
3. dice_coef: 0.7114

As can be observed, the loss and dice coefficient are not entirely bad. However, on the other hand, the accuracy is disastrous.

I have also obtained the MeanIoU and it has a strange behavior: It starts at 0.4619 and remains the same in all epochs.

Why could this be happening? Could it be an error in the network and that it is calculating the accuracy incorrectly?

Thank you all.

Comment: Have you inspected some predictions visually?